# When using filter on the graph API, how to do you only return data where a field isn't blank

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

When using filter on the graph API, how to do you only return data where a field / property isn't blank
currenty doing `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=EmployeeId ge '!'` but these doesn't seem the correct way to do this... doing `EmployeeId ne ''` isn't allowed it seems. This field is blank not null when not filled in, atleast in my tenant anyway.

```
...
"displayName": "Test Example",
"employeeId": "000Blah",
...
```

Any one able to confirm if this is the correct way?

Basicly only want to return the records where people do have their employeeId filled in.

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There currently is no filter capability in graph on the users endpoint to do null(or empty) filtering. I believe there are requests all over the internet asking microsoft to implement it, however as it stands, there is no correct way to do it. your work around seems as good as any.

Here is a user voice request for it https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests/suggestions/36040288-useful-user-endpoint-filtering you can vote for it

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the `$filter` does not support `-ne`, but per my test, it supports `-eq`, that means you can get the users who did not fill the `employeeId`(just a tip, not sure if it helps).

**Note:** You should know the counts of the blanks in the `employeeId`, it means the (hit the space bar once) is different from (hit the space bar twice).

My workaround is to use the powershell to do that, make sure you have [installed the `AzureAD` module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/install-adv2?view=azureadps-2.0) and use `Connect-AzureAD` to login.

Use the command below, you can get the users who filled the `employeeId`. In my sample, I use only one blank.

```
Get-AzureADUser -All $true | Where-Object {$_.ExtensionProperty.employeeId -ne ' '}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This should do the job

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=userType eq 'Member' and employeeId ge ' '
```

Please notice the space.