# Filtering on "null" or "no values"

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to make a filter in Graph API, querying for employees without phone, but with no luck.
This is a part of the query I am working on.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=userType eq 'Member'&$select = businessPhones
```

This results in something like this:

```
{   "businessPhones": ["+473456789"]},
{   "businessPhones": ["+479876543"]},
{   "businessPhones": ["+471234567"]}
```

What I am trying to do is ask for users without a businessphone

```
{      "businessPhones": []}
```

Something like this

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=userType eq 'Member' and businessPhones eq ''
```

However, I have no clue on how to do this. Anyone?

**EDIT, thanks Tiny Wang for pointing out "no filtering support":**

businessPhones does not support filtering. However, assignedLicenses does. If I want to query for users without any assignedLicenses

```
{ "assignedLicenses" : [] }
```

How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Could you pls share you idea on the filter? According to the document, it's true that we can't do filter on "businessPhones". How about filter it manually in your code?

Comment: I just want to extract those without a BusinessPhone set. 
I want all users with { "businessPhones": [] }
The complete filter is somewhat more advanced, with employeeID etc., but that is not relevant here.

Comment: Following the OData Grammer, we should use `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=not assignedLicenses/any()` or `assignedLicenses/$count eq 0` here, but they all failed in my side, you may test it again. I think it's more likely to be a bug or issue.

Answer (score 2):

Pls note, according to the api properity doc, `businessPhones` isn't a properity supporting $filter, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/user?view=graph-rest-beta#properties

[image]

==========================UPDATE============================

Per my testing, I think it's also an unachievable task. It seems there're some 'defect' exists in ms graph OData filter. In this case, we need to use `not assignedLicenses/any()` according to [OData protocol](https://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/errata03/os/complete/part2-url-conventions/odata-v4.0-errata03-os-part2-url-conventions-complete.html#_Toc453752358).

[image]
[image]

But according to my testing result, the query doesn't support using `assignedLicenses/any()`->`Error: Complex query on property assignedLicenses is not supported` , `not assignedLicenses/any()`->`Error: Unsupported Query"`, but only support like `assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq 3b555118-xxxx-e2096870)`.

What's more, when executing below query, it returns error `Complex query on property assignedLicenses is not supported.`

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=userType eq 'Member' and assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq 3b555118-xxxx-2096870)&$select=assignedLicenses
```

But when executing this, it worked, so weird.

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users?$filter=assignedLicenses/any(x:x/skuId eq 3b555118-xxxxxx-df1e2096870)&$select=assignedLicenses
```

[image]

I also tried to use `$count` property to do the filter, but also failed:

[image]

Comment: Let me refrase, assignedLicenses supports filter. How can I extract users without any assigned licenses? eg: { assignedLicenses : [] }

Comment: Thanks for you effort, Tiny Wang. You walked pretty much the same path as me. I can not even grasp if it suppose to work or if I am doing something wrong. I guess the task I am about to solve need to be done (for now) through lifting the dataset to the client and just scan the entire dataset.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm pushing myself for answer accepted. And I think it's better to filter one more time after getting the query result so that we don't need to put effert for the request url any more. Sorry for no help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same task. After some research, I figured out how to filter out null string properties such as `jobTitle`, `department`, etc. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62406629/when-using-filter-on-the-graph-api-how-to-do-you-only-return-data-where-a-field).

Based on the answer, I tried the following query, and It works for me.

`https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=NOT (businessPhones/any(p:p ge ' '))&$count=true`

Be sure that you specified whitespace between quotes `' '`.